# Can't upgrade within Ubuntu or from boot

Tags: boot, bios

I'm a Linux beginner. I've used Ubuntu for a year but only for the every day stuff.

I tried to reinstall Windows 7 on many occasions but it kept coming up with errors.
I had tried lots of different things and was getting fed up, so I thought I would switch my 79 year old grandma to Ubuntu.

Also had problems, it looked like grub Ubuntu start screen when cd/dvd boot, tryed live cd, install, memtest is all that has showed.

Anytime I clicked install it would pretty much take me to live cd with an error.
I spent all night making new dvds of different Linuxs trying each and everyone, turning legacy boots on and off, secure boot enable/disable, replacing Ram, even though test came back fine.

I took out my HDD and placed it in to my grandmas laptop, It worked showing all of her laptop specs. I then took my Grandma HDD out of her laptop and placed it into my laptop and install Ubuntu 12.04 like that

Swapped them back over and it was working, but with many Problems.

Ubuntu software centre isn't opening, well something is opening and closing  with a blink of the eye.

Additional drivers, isn't opening

`sudo apt-get install <anything>` returns errors

I have tried to update/upgrade from boot cd/dvd but no luck.

Comment: Sounds like hardware problems. What laptop model is it? Does it have graphics card?

Comment: Notebook model: hp 650 notebook Pc
Product Number : B7B07ES#ABU
System board 1858
Processor type : intel(r) Pentium(r) CPU b970 @ 230ghz
Total memory: 6gb

I am not sure of the graphics as it doesn't say on the system information on bios.

Comment: UPDATE!!! When I try to install 14.04 from boot, I see the following error Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14 - I will try another hdd in the laptop to see if I can format and install on that.